# How do I get this if - else command, when using Dir.glob to let me know when the file does not exists

Tags: ruby

I have successfully build a file finder with Dir.glob but now am wanting to know if the file is not found as well - dealing with 1000's of files so I need to know if one is not found.

The code I have is this:

```
 # code above gets a file name from a list of in a file then I search the computer for the file:

 Dir.glob("#{folder}/**/#{search_file_name}")  do |f|  

 if File.exists?(f)
     puts "the file name #{f} is found"
     puts "now I am working on #{f}"  
 else
     puts "the file #{f} cannot be found"

     end

    #the rest of the code moves the file to a another directory if found.
```

This works well for files that exists.  But if the file does not exists I do not get a message in the terminal to that effect.       I am missing something obvious.  Perhaps my Dir.glob only holds the files it finds so that |f| never passes a file to the if statement if it does not exists.

Comment: `Dir.glob` is unlikely to return something that doesn't exist unless in that very short period of time someone else deleted that file or directory. How would it find something if it didn't exist?

Comment: Thank you.  I can see what i was trying to do was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't iterate through an empty Array. There is no need to set a conditional with File.exist?. Dir.glob will return [] if the file can not be found.

```
def find_files(folder, search_file_name)
  file = Dir.glob("#{folder}/**/#{search_file_name}")
  puts "the file #{search_file_name} can't be found" if file.empty?
  file.each do |f|
    puts "the file name #{f} is found"
    puts "now I am working on #{f}" 
  end
end
```

Comment: I added an edit to this - not sure if it was approved but I could not get it to work until I removed the "return" before "puts "the file #{search_file_name} can't be found" if file.empty?" line.